# Any help with this code (source text based game)

Tags: cipher

Source: Torn.com (text based rpg game)

31 30 35 20 31 32 31 20 31 30 31 20 36 38
20 37 30 20 37 31 20 35 34 20 31 31 39 20
31 31 34 20 37 34 20 37 35 20 36 35 20 31
32 32 20 31 30 36 20 35 33 20 31 30 38 20
31 30 31 20 37 33 20 31 31 36 20 31 31 32
20 39 30 20 31 31 34 20 31 31 31 20 38 32
20 38 34 20 31 31 31 20 31 31 30 20 38 39
20 31 31 35 20 35 37 20 31 30 39 20 36 36
20 35 38 20 35 38 20 34 39 20 35 30 20 35
31 20 35 32 20 35 33 20 35 34 20 00 00 00

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of a question posted yesterday... https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87069/any-help-with-this-code

Comment: @Stiv I agree, but this one lists the source and the other one doesn't. If anything, I'd say change the close reason for the other one to mark it as a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 5):

Some observation:

> The numbers look like hexadecimal ASCII values of digits separated by spaces.
>  If so, they decode to this sequence (with trailing zeros dropped):
>
> `105 121 101 68 70 71 54 119 114 74 75 65 122 106 53 108 101 73 116 112 90 114 111 82 84 111 110 89 115 57 109 66 58 58 49 50 51 52 53 54`
>
>  This in turn, looks like another set of decimal ASCII values.
>  If so, it decodes to this message:
>
>  `iyeDFG6wrJKAzj5leItpZroRTonYs9mB::123456`
>
>  Whatever that means??

Comment: Okay so I tried that on the website I found it on (source listed above) and it says incorrect

Comment: It's only a partial answer. It probably needs further decoding - a third or even more steps.

Comment: Any help to further decode this?